# Synchronize a single file between a specific OneDrive folder and a specific SharePoint library

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive-for-business, sync

I have an existing **SharePoint Library S** which contains a certain **File X**. File X is edited frequently, but in a different location, namely in a certain, existing **OneDrive Folder O**.

How can I keep the two instances of File **X** in both locations **S** and **O** in sync with each other?

Comment: Does it work? If yes, please kindly mark my response as the solution/answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Via **PowerAutomate** using 2 flows.

**NOTE:** Beware that this might lead to endless flow triggers. If that is the case, I believe just use a single Automated Cloud Flow for the use case where file is updated most frequently from. For the other way round, just manually replace the files, or run it as an Instant Cloud Flow, but disable the other Cloud Flow first before doing so.

1. 1st flow as an **Automated Cloud Flow** to *update SharePoint file X* **when One Drive file X is modified**

[image]

2. 2nd flow to *update One Drive file X* **when SharePoint file X is modified**

[image]